# Merge DataFrames in Pandas using the mean

Tags: python, merge, pandas

I have a set of DataFrames with numeric values and partly overlapping indices. I would like to merge them an take the mean if an index occurs in more than one DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], columns=['col'], index=['a','b','c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([4,5,6], columns=['col'], index=['b','c','d'])
```

This gives me two DataFrames:

```
   col            col
a    1        b     4
b    2        c     5
c    3        d     6
```

Now I would like to merge the DataFrames and take the mean for each index (if applicable, i.e. if it occurs more than once).

Should look like this:

```
    col
a     1
b     3
c     4
d     6
```

Can I do this with some advanced merging/joining?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

something like this:

```
df3 = pd.concat((df1, df2))
df3.groupby(df3.index).mean()

#    col
# a    1
# b    3
# c    4
# d    6
```

or other way around, as in @unutbu answer:

```
pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1).mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was fast. Pandas is so amazingly simple.

Answer (score 5):

```
In [22]: pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer').mean(axis=1)
Out[23]: 
a    1
b    3
c    4
d    6
dtype: float64
```

---

Regarding Roman's question, I find [IPython](http://ipython.org/)'s `%timeit` command a convenient way to benchmark code:

```
In [28]: %timeit df3 = pd.concat((df1, df2)); df3.groupby(df3.index).mean()
1000 loops, best of 3: 617 µs per loop

In [29]: %timeit pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer').mean(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 577 µs per loop

In [39]: %timeit pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1).mean(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 524 µs per loop
```

In this case, `pd.concat(...).mean(...)` turns out to be a bit faster. But really we should test bigger dataframes to get a more meaningful benchmark.

By the way, if you do not want to install IPython, equivalent benchmarks can be run using [Python's `timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html). It just takes a bit more setup. The [docs has some examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#examples) showing how to do this.

---

Note that if `df1` or `df2` were to have duplicate entries in its index, for example like this:

```
N = 1000
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]*N, columns=['col'], index=['a','b','c']*N)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([4,5,6]*N, columns=['col'], index=['b','c','d']*N)
```

then these three answers give different results:

```
In [56]: df3 = pd.concat((df1, df2)); df3.groupby(df3.index).mean()
Out[56]: 
   col
a    1
b    3
c    4
d    6
```

`pd.merge` probably does not give the kind of answer you want:

```
In [58]: len(pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer').mean(axis=1))
Out[58]: 2002000
```

While `pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1)` raises a ValueError:

```
In [48]: pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1)
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Comment: +1 I'm still learning Pandas. Which of the 2 solutions will be faster?

Comment: Good question ;) I'll try both on some larger data. First answer wins though.

Comment: @unutbu thanks for benchmarking answers, I definitely need more practice on Pandas and Data Analysis, though..

Comment: One small thing: If I had more columns in the DataFrames, how would I define that I want to merge and average 'col' and do another/no operation on the others?

Comment: @MartinPreusse: You could apply any of the above methods to the Series `df1['col']` and `df2['col']`. For example, @Roman's answer would look like this: `pd.concat((df1['col'], df2['col']), axis=1).mean(axis=1)`.