# Merge DataFrames in Pandas using arbitrary weights

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question is very similar to: [Merge DataFrames in Pandas using the mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490064/merge-dataframes-in-pandas-using-the-mean), but I need to use arbitrary weights, not just the simple mean.

I have two DFs that look like this:

df1

| from_code | to_code | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | 0.2 |
| a | b | 0.4 |

df2

| from_code | to_code | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | 0.3 |
| a | b | 0.5 |
| a | c | 0.7 |

The columns are the same. The values in from_code and to_code are *not* necessarily the same. There's a lot of overlap, but df1 may have some values in from_code and to_code that do not exist in df2.

I also have weights w1 and w2 that sum to 1. Say w1 = 0.1 and w2 = 0.9

What I want to is merge the two dataframes to get a new one that would look like this:

| from_code | to_code | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | 0.29 |
| a | b | 0.49 |
| a | c | 0.63 |

Note that the frequency in the new table is w1 * (frequency from df1) + w2 * (frequency from df2). If a row is missing from df1 or df2, then the frequency should be treated as zero.

Note that if I had w1 = w2 = 0.5, then I'm just taking the mean. I can solve for that special case as follows:

```
merged_df = pd.concat((df1, df2))
final_df = merged_df.groupby(['from_code', 'to_code']).mean().reset_index()
```

In general, I may have more than 2 dfs, generally between 2 and 4 but the number will be a variable. I figure if I can get help solving for the case of 2 dfs I can generalize for n dfs, but if anyone wants to go even farther and give me a general solution, that'd be cool.

While I wait for an awesome answer, I'm going to try and create an intermediary table that looks like this:

| from_code_1 | to_code_1 | freq_1 | w_1 | from_code_2 | to_code_2 | freq_2 | w_2 | new_freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | 0.2 | 0.1 | a | a | 0.3 | 0.9 | [calc] |
| a | b | 0.4 | 0.1 | a | b | 0.5 | 0.9 | [calc] |
| a | c | 0.0 | 0.1 | a | c | 0.7 | 0.9 | [calc] |

I'll try to kludge my way through creating that table, populating the new_freq, and then reducing the table back to just three columns (from_code, to_code, new_freq), but I am hopeful that there is a more elegant way to do this using Pandas merge or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the weights to the `frequency` of each DataFrame, and then `concat` and `groupby` as you did (but take the sum instead of the mean):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'from_code': ['a','a'],
                    'to_code':['a','b'],
                    'frequency':[0.2, 0.4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'from_code': ['a','a', 'a'],
                    'to_code':['a','b','c'],
                    'frequency':[0.3, 0.5, 0.7]})

# weight the values
df1['frequency'] *= 0.1
df2['frequency'] *= 0.9

# aggregate
output = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['from_code', 'to_code']).sum().reset_index()
```

Resulting `output`:

```
  from_code to_code  frequency
0         a       a       0.29
1         a       b       0.49
2         a       c       0.63
```

The general formula would to have a list of DataFrames and a list of weights, loop to apply the weights and then aggregate.

I wasn't sure if this was the case or not from your description, but there is an assumption that in each DataFrame, the rows are unique with respect to the  `from_code` and `to_code` (as is shown in your example).  If not, an additional `groupby` would have to be performed on each DataFrame to resolve multiple observations of one code.

This also modifies the original DataFrames; this could be avoided by copying the data before applying the weights.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. (And yes, the rows are unique with respect to from_code and to_code.)

Comment: So, it turns out this code isn't actually working. Here's my exact code (column names are slightly different than my example in the original post):

# concatenates
new_tm = pd.concat(original_trans_mats[prefix_key])

# adds the new col with new weight
new_tm['new_weight'] = new_tm['rel_frequency'] * new_tm['weight']

# drops old rel_frequency and weight cols
new_tm = new_tm.drop(['rel_frequency', 'weight'], axis=1)

# groups by two columns I'm keeping, sums on new_weight
new_tm.groupby(['from_str', 'to_char']).sum().reset_index()

Comment: The problem is that after running that code, I *don't* have unique rows. I have duplicates where from_str and to_char are the same (but weight is different). So it didn't actually do a groupby on from_str and to_char, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I needed:

new_tm = new_tm = new_tm.groupby(['from_str', 'to_char']).sum().reset_index()